# Pass-through authentication for mobile apps written in ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

In ionic2, is it possible for an mobile app to share data with an different app? For example App1 stores a piece of data in a storage, and App2 read the data that stored by App1.  Below is the reason why:

I am using ionic2 to build mobile applications for my company. So far we have 3 mobile apps. Each app needs to know who the user is, so it required user to sign in.

We are looking for a solution that only requires users to sign to one of our firm mobile apps, then the rest of firm apps will know who the user is.

Here what I am thinking, don't know if this is possible.  I am thinking to store user's Id on a global storage on the device, then all our apps read will go read the Id from that global storage to identify who the user is.

Comment: Why not store user and device ID in cloud?

Comment: I was thinking about that, however, the UUID is changing for every app.